# Append Query Error during Service Refresh

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Hello I am working on a dashboard that needs to combine 2 tables: **sales table, sales order table**. Two two tables come from different sources: sales table from SAP BW and sales order table through a dataflow. Both tables have a number of applied steps that delete, reformat and rename the columns. I then want to append the Sales Order Table to the Sales table. In the desktop version everything works even if I hit "refresh all" in the Power Query Editor. When I publish the report to the service and refresh, I am getting an error saying: **The key didn't match any rows in the table**

Full Error Message:

[image]

After troubleshooting for the last couple of days I'm pretty sure that the issue has to do with my column names being renamed. However its strange that the append would work in desktop but not in service.

My main questions are:

1. Can you append tables after multiple applied transformation steps?
2. Can the tables both refresh daily or does one or the other have to be static?
3. Does the order of the table queries in query editor effect the order in which tables are loaded or does everything load all at once? Can this order affect my append query?

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated. I am 99% of the way to launching this new report but this refresh issue is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can append tables after multiple applied transformation steps
2. Both tables can refresh daily
3. The order of the table queries in query editor doesn't matter. Power BI will determine the order in which they are loaded. E.g. if you want to append a table to another table, that other table is loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering those questions Peter. I concluded that the issue had something to do with appending a dataflow. I switched to a new data source from SAP BW and its working now. What's interesting is that the dataflow is still being imported and refreshed daily so the issue had to do with just the append.